# center a item vertical on drag touch detect overlap

Tags: touch, drag, setinterval, collision, overlap

I need to position the center of each column each item after a few seconds in the red rectangle touch and detect which item is more inside the red rectangle, to move to the center.

[link here](http://proyectos.ilogica.cl/bancoestado/brasil-movil/)

```
<div id="snap"></div><!--- center here a .item on touch and overlap after  x seconds --->
            <div class="cont-area"></div>

            <div class="overflow-items" id="comere">
                <div class="cont-items">

                        <div class="item">
                            1
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            2
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            3
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            4
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            1
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            2
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            3
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            4
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```